# Spring MVC return hibernate object with lazy loaded field to AjaxResponseBuilder

Tags: javascript, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc, lazy-loading

Lets say I have an Person object:

```
 String name = "bob";
 Int number = 3;
 String lastName = ?
```

and the lastName field is lazy loaded with Hibernate. When I want to

```
 AjaxResponseBuilder builder = AjaxResponseBuilder.success();
 builder.addData("person", Person");
```

I get a HibernateLazyLoad Exception because lastName hasn't been fetched. Is there a way I can pass the rest of the object without this exception? So far I can just set lastName to null and pass the object just fine, but that seems like a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: What is AjaxResponseBuilder ?

Comment: @bhantol Its a Spring thing used to build a response to an Ajax request in Java

Comment: The session already closed. You probably need to configure the `OpenSessionInViewFilter` which keeps the session open for the current thread.

Comment: @Bart what if i don't need the lazyloaded property? I just want to pass it without the lazy field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that AjaxResponseBuilder wants to access lastName field of the Person object (probably it just goes over all the fields). You have the following choices:

1. Do not make the field lazy: add lazy="false" to .hbm (or corresponding annotation)
2. Initialize the fields on person object before passing it to the builder:

   ```
   Hibernate.initialize(person);
   ```
3. Add OpenSessionInViewFilter in your web.xml (as suggested above):

   ```
   <filter>
     <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   ```

If there is some sort of configuration for AjaxResponseBuilder that tells it to omit lastName field from its lookup, that should also work.